# Редирект на главную вместо 404 (Joomla 2.5.4)

Tags: редирект, joomla, php

Добрый день! Есть такая проблемка: при обращении к несуществующей странице, происходит редирект на главную страницу. Причём, я открываю консоль Mozilla Firefox и смотрю что передаётся в заголовках (какие коды и т.п.), так вот в заголовках я не вижу ни `404` кода ни `301`, хотя в консоли стоит флажок "Не очищать" (т.е. по идеи он мне все логи должен сохранить). Смотрел файл `.htaccess` ничего подозрительного не нашёл:

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
#Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

#redirect /osteklenie-balk/product/view/6/8.html http://www.stella-drev.ru/kontakty.html
RedirectMatch ^([0-9a-zA-Z\/\-\_]*)product/view/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www.stella-drev.ru/404.html
#redirect ^([0-9a-z-_/]*)/product/view/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www.stella-drev.ru/kontakty.html [R=permanent]
```

Попытался сделать вот так http://qdev.ru/custom-error-page-in-joomla17 , тоже ничего. Файл `error.php` существует в папке с шаблоном, но там прописано следующее:

```
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die(); 
echo file_get_contents(JURI::root().'/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=115');
```

На сайте есть нормальная страница `404`, доступна по адресу www.доменное_имя.ru/404 (создана как материалсайта), в какой момент 404 перестал работать - непонятно. Куда копать не пойму. Смотрел файл шаблона там тоже ничего. Сайт под управлением joomla 2.5.4, `mod_rewrite` включен, пере адресация включена. Заранее спасибо! С уважением.

19:09:2012 - новые повороты в деле о `404` ошибке.

По запросу в службу поддержки хостинга - выяснилось что, `404` ошибку как-то ломает вот этот код в `.htaccess` :

```
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Как ни странно, код этот сформирован joomla и во всех остальных случаях работает нормально. У кого есть мысли пишите.

Comment: Добрый день так и  не удалось победить проблему? аналогично у меня один в один)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой же ёжик в частности виновата строка

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Когда-то давно я сам поставил редирект на главную вместо ошибки 404 и теперь где я его поставил найти не могу в итоге и вылезла такая проблема.

Решил полной пересборкой всех компонентов на новой версии джумлы, так как простое обновление до актуальной версии не помогло. После это страница 404 заработала как надо.